# sequence id in oracle

Tags: oracle-11g, plsql

I am using Oracle 11g.

I have a senario like:

I need to increase auto increment id like below

```
00000001
00000002
00000003
00000004
```

For example, my table looks like below

```
id       empid name    sal
000001   10    raju    5555
000002   20    ramesh  6666
000003   30    rahul   55555
```

Now if I insert a record into that table the id needs to increase automatically.

How can I achieve this in a stored procedure? I have an insert statement in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually achieved by using a sequence, often in combination with a trigger that fires for each row, before an insert.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_seq;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_my_table_bir
BEFORE INSERT ON MyTable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF :new.my_id IS NULL THEN
      :new.my_id := my_seq.NEXTVAL;
   END IF;
END;
```

But of course you're free to get that next value in your own stored procedure and insert it from there; if you use a trigger like the one above, it won't get another value from the sequence if one is already provided.

---

Please note that while the numbers from the sequence are guaranteed to be *unique* — you will not get the same number twice unless you reset the sequence — they are not guarateed to be *dense* — gaps in the numbering can and will occur.